# Where is send() implemented in OpenMPI?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

In OpenMPI, if I follow the call stack of any collective operation (e.g  MPI_Reduce) deep enough, I find that it calls a function called send().

After a lot of grepping, I'm not sure where send() is implemented. I suspect that send() may be buried inside of a macro or obscure shim layer of some sort.

**Where are the implementation(s) of send() located in the OpenMPI codebase?**

I'm looking at OpenMPI v1.8.1, though I suspect that the organization of the sorce tree hasn't changed that much between versions.

Comment: That send() is most likely the POSIX system call - it's implemented in the operating system, not within MPI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`send(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) is the BSD socket system call for sending data over network sockets. It is ultimately used by the `tcp` BTL of Open MPI to perform the actual network transfer from one process to another and its implementation is to be found in the source code of the standard C library and in the OS kernel.

If you are interested in the actual higher-level mechanism that Open MPI uses to transmit messages from one rank to another over TCP/IP networks, then the `tcp` BTL itself is to be found in `$OMPI_SOURCE/ompi/mca/btl/tcp/` (for older Open MPI versions) or in `$OMPI_SOURCE/opal/mca/btl/tcp/` (for newer versions).